# PrimeNG tree icons

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using PrimeNG tree. Below is the code for the same

```
<p-tree *ngIf="Nodes" [value]="Nodes" selectionMode="single" [(selection)]="selectedNode">
                <ng-template let-node pTemplate type="default">
                    <span>
                        <img class="tree-icon" src="{{node.icon}}" />
                    </span>
                    <span class="ui-treenode-label ui-corner-all" [title]="node.description">{{node.label}}</span> 
                </ng-template>
                 <ng-template let-node pTemplate="editNode">
                    <span>
                        <img class="tree-icon" src="{{node.icon}}" />
                    </span>
                    <input id="newFolderInput" [(ngModel)]="node.label" type="text" style="width:100%">
                </ng-template>
```

The issue is that the icons are not appearing. Also in the rendered html, there is no img tag. Can somebody tell me what is the issue here or how can I debug it ?

Comment: Will you be able to share your **Nodes** json structure?

Comment: if you looking for expanding icons to add, add them to the json tree and then there is no need to add them in the template.  this.filesTree8 = [
            {
                expandedIcon: "fa-folder-open",
                collapsedIcon: "fa-folder"
            }
        ];